# Can space-time get torn apart?

Tags: spacetime, string-theory

Here's an interesting comment from phsyics forums

> I think that there are a variety of interpretations of the underlying structure of the universe. However, you can think of energy as creating the fabric in which it exists. Each particle has an energy distribution and the energy at a particular point in space is determined by the sum of the energy contibutions of every particle in the universe at that point in space. The total energy density at each point provides a type of thickness to the universe at that point, where energy is like rubber in that it pulls in the universe together (think of a rubber band that is stretched and that is thicker at some points). Accordingly, in high energy density (thick) space, space is smaller and time is slower If you look at a ruler in high energy density area while standing in a low energy density area, the ruler will be smaller and a clock will tick slower.
>
> Anyway, if you have a rip in space time (an area of zero energy density), particles or waves directed at the rip would appear to be reflected away from it sort of like anti-gravity (quantum mechanically, a rip is similar a forbidden zone, although if you were completly encircled by a rip, you couldn't tunnel through). You wouldn't be able to see the rip. If you were encircled by a rip, it would make you invisible. It would be the same as creating your own island universe. It is similar to what happens with a black hole. In an expanding universe, from the frame of the black hole, the outer universe between black holes is so thin as to almost be a rip. You can think about the universe as being a giant ballon with the thickness of the rubber being determined by the energy density of the baloon and particles are like accoustic waves traveling through the baloon. A rip in space time will affect particle waves in a similar way as a hole in the ballon affects accoustic waves, except that the universe wouldn't deflate.

Further;

> As I see it, the energy density of mass extends beyond the position of the mass, so that the energy density of a black hole extends infinetly in an inverse square manner form the black hole even though all of the mass of the black hole is at a point. It is the gradient of the energy density that creates the appearence of gravitational acceleration. Also, the energy density provides a thickness to the universe. The extreme thinning of energy density is like a whole in space in the same sense that a worn thin part of a bed sheet is seen to have a hole. Although, it is a relative concept.
>
> Accordingly, my idea for a "ripped space force field" is to locally redistribute the energy density such that all of the energy density in one region of space is displaced into the adjacent region which creates a sort of rip in space, since it creates a large energy density gradient that causes particles to gravitationally accelerate away from the gap such that almost no energy would flow through the energy density gap.

I've heard that we cannot have absolute zero energy anywhere in the universe, due to Heisenberg uncertainty principle.  And a "rip" in spacetime means zero energy density, so this is not possible? A slightly above layman but well below  physics degree explanation would be nice.

Topology change of space-time is probably impossible in general relativity, or 
that's what I managed to gather. But what about it in string theory, is this an actual possibility or am I talking science fiction here.

I know this has been asked before, but the answers weren't satisfactory to me.

Thanks.

Reference https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/can-you-rip-the-space-time-fabric.391606/page-2

Comment: This sounds like pseudoscience quackery to me. "Ripping spacetime" and "energy densities extending infinitely" are all bad signs, coupled with the fact that it seems to imply that energy creates space and time. You'd be best disregarding what you read on that forum post.

Comment: "seems to imply that energy creates space and time. " Well,  space time as just a metric for mathematical convenience is no longer a correct description. AFAIK space-time, like other quantum fields, is the graviton field, and behaves like other fields too, having fluctuations and a non zero energy value everywhere

Comment: No energy just means it's a flat spacetime. Not "nothingness"

Comment: Flat spacetime still has a non zero energy density everywhere. I feel like you're thinking in GR terms, which obviously will not work if you go all the way down

Comment: My point is that energy determines the LOCAL GEOMETRY of a manifold, but it doesn't create spacetime

Comment: About empty space : *"I wished to show that space-time is not necessarily something to which one can ascribe a separate existence, independently  of the actual objects of physical reality. Physical objects are not in space, but these objects are spatially extended. In this way the concept 'empty space' loses its meaning"* - A.Einstein (Relativity);
And about " the energy at a particular point in space is determined by the sum of the energy contributions of every particle in the universe at that point in space." - this sounds like Casimir effect and vacuum energy/entanglement (M-theory brane)

Comment: [in Newtonian approximation]  *"$h_{\mu\nu}$ are so small compared to 1 that we can neglect the higher powers of $h_{\mu\nu}$ and their derivatives. If we do that, we learn nothing about the structure of the gravitation field, or of the metrical space of cosmical dimensions, but we do learn about the influence of neighbouring masses upon physical phenomena"*-A.Einstein. Our classical perspective gives us the impression that only local contributions are important, but we get this impression only if we neglect *"metrical space of cosmical dimensions"*. Note: $g_{\mu\nu}=\eta_{\mu\nu}+h_{\mu\nu}$